# wrong attribute when php calling varchar mysql into html

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have some field in my table like this :

```
Field Name   |   DataType    | Length  |
----------------------------------------
NAME         |   VARCHAR     |   50    |
```

I fill this table like this :

```
NAME         |
--------------
Irfan        |
Lusye Agnes  |
Helda        |
```

So, I Use php in codeigniter to get the datas, then I view it into html in 'select option'. The code is like this :

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="selectError1">Addressed To :</label>
     <div class="controls">
       <select id="selectError1" multiple data-rel="chosen" class="input-xlarge">
    <?php
       foreach ($datas as $data) {
         echo "<option value=" .$data['Name']. " >" . $data['Name'] . "</option>";
       }
    ?>

    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I debug the code using firebug.
The problem is, where the field have space like 'Lusye agnes', firebug identified like this :

```
<select id="selectError1" class="input-xlarge chzn-done" data-rel="chosen"">
   <option value="Irfan">Irfan </option>
   <option agnes="" value="Lusye">Lusye Agnes</option>
   <option value="Helda">Helda</option>
</select>
```

How can I make it correct ?

Comment: Can you try this: `echo "<option value='".$data['Name']."'>".$data['Name']."</option>";` in your foreach loop..

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="selectError1">Addressed To :</label>
     <div class="controls">
       <select id="selectError1" multiple data-rel="chosen" class="input-xlarge">
    <?php
       foreach ($datas as $data) {
         echo "<option value='".$data['Name']."'>".$data['Name']."</option>";
       }
    ?>

    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectError1">Addressed To :</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="selectError1" multiple data-rel="chosen" class="input-xlarge">
            <?php foreach ($datas as $data) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data['Name']; ?>"><?php echo $data['Name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using " after 'value=', you should Try this:

```
<select id="selectError1" multiple data-rel="chosen" class="input-xlarge">
<?php
   foreach ($datas as $data) {
     echo "<option value='" .$data['Name']. "' >" . $data['Name'] . "</option>";
   }
?>

</select>
```